# ValueError: could not convert string to float: id

Tags: python, string, floating-point, type-conversion, valueerror

I'm running the following Python script:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python

import os,sys
from scipy import stats
import numpy as np

f = open('data2.txt', 'r').readlines()
for i in range(0, len(f)-1):
    l1 = f[i].split()
    list1 = [float(x) for x in l1]
```

However I got the errors like:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: id
```

I'm confused by this.

When I try this for only one line in interactive section, instead of for loop using script:

```py
from scipy import stats
import numpy as np

f = open('data2.txt','r').readlines()
l1 = f[1].split()
list1 = [float(x) for x in l1]
list1
# [5.3209183842, 4.6422726719, 4.3788135547]
```

it works well. What is the explanation a little bit about this?

Comment: This kind of error `ValueError: could not convert string to float: ` can occur when reading a dataframe from a `csv` file with types as `df = df[['p']].astype({'p': float})`. If the `csv` was recorded with empty spaces, python will not recognize the space character as a nan. You will need to overwrite empty cells with NaN with `df = df.replace(r'^\s*$', np.nan, regex=True)`

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Obviously some of your lines don't have valid float data, specifically some line have text `id` which can't be converted to float.

When you try it in interactive prompt you are trying only first line, so best way is to print the line where you are getting this error and you will know the wrong line e.g.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os,sys
from scipy import stats
import numpy as np

f=open('data2.txt', 'r').readlines()
N=len(f)-1
for i in range(0,N):
    w=f[i].split()
    l1=w[1:8]
    l2=w[8:15]
    try:
        list1=[float(x) for x in l1]
        list2=[float(x) for x in l2]
    except ValueError,e:
        print "error",e,"on line",i
    result=stats.ttest_ind(list1,list2)
    print result[1]
```

Answer (score 37):

My error was very simple: the text file containing the data had some **space** (so not visible) character on the last line.

As an output of grep, I had `45`  instead of just `45`.

Comment: Spaces and tabs are visible ;) End-of-lines and alikes are not, for example, characters `\n`,`\r`.

Comment: I guess this is the point in time when most people figure out that  [Lib/re.py](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html) and .replace(' ', '') exist.

Answer (score 23):

This error is pretty verbose:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: id
```

*Somewhere* in your text file, a line has the word `id` in it, which can't really be converted to a number.

Your test code works because the word `id` isn't present in `line 2`.

---

If you want to catch that line, try this code. I cleaned your code up a tad:

```python
#!/usr/bin/python

import os, sys
from scipy import stats
import numpy as np

for index, line in enumerate(open('data2.txt', 'r').readlines()):
    w = line.split(' ')
    l1 = w[1:8]
    l2 = w[8:15]

    try:
        list1 = map(float, l1)
        list2 = map(float, l2)
    except ValueError:
        print 'Line {i} is corrupt!'.format(i = index)'
        break

    result = stats.ttest_ind(list1, list2)
    print result[1]
```

Answer (score 18):

For a Pandas dataframe with a column of numbers with commas, use this:

```
df["Numbers"] = [float(str(i).replace(",", "")) for i in df["Numbers"]]
```

So values like `4,200.42` would be converted to `4200.42` as a float.

Bonus 1: This is *fast*.

Bonus 2: More space efficient if saving that dataframe in something like [Apache Parquet](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_parquet.html) format.

Answer (score 8):

Perhaps your numbers aren't actually numbers, but letters masquerading as numbers?

In my case, the font I was using meant that "l" and "1" looked very similar. I had a string like 'l1919' which I thought was '11919' and that messed things up.

Answer (score 7):

Your data may not be what you expect -- it seems you're expecting, but not getting, floats.

A simple solution to figuring out where this occurs would be to add a try/except to the for-loop:

```
for i in range(0,N):
    w=f[i].split()
    l1=w[1:8]
    l2=w[8:15]
    try:
      list1=[float(x) for x in l1]
      list2=[float(x) for x in l2]
    except ValueError, e:
      # report the error in some way that is helpful -- maybe print out i
    result=stats.ttest_ind(list1,list2)
    print result[1]
```

Answer (score 6):

Shortest way:

`df["id"] = df['id'].str.replace(',', '').astype(float)`  - if ',' is the problem

`df["id"] = df['id'].str.replace(' ', '').astype(float)` - if blank space is the problem

Comment: This is short and sweet. Sometimes the error could be because of the wrong decimal sign `,` instead of '.'. In this case `.str.replace(",", ".").astype(float)` will work.

Answer (score 2):

Update empty string values with 0.0 values:
if you know the possible non-float values  then update it.

```
df.loc[df['score'] == '', 'score'] = 0.0


df['score']=df['score'].astype(float)
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved the similar situation with basic technique using pandas. First load the csv or text file using pandas.It's pretty simple

```
data=pd.read_excel('link to the file')
```

Then set the index of data to the respected column that needs to be changed. For example, if your data has ID as one attribute or column, then set index to ID.

```
 data = data.set_index("ID")
```

Then delete all the rows with "id" as the value instead of number using following command.

```
  data = data.drop("id", axis=0).
```

Hope, this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

### In pandas

This error (or a very similar error) commonly appears when changing the dtype of a pandas column from `object` to `float` using `astype()` or `apply()`. The cause is there are non-numeric strings that cannot be converted into floats. One solution is to use `pd.to_numeric()` instead, with `errors='coerce'` passed. This replaces non-numeric values such as the literal string `'id'` to NaN.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': ['id', '1.5', '2.4']})

df['col'] = df['col'].astype(float)                     # <---- ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'id'
df['col'] = df['col'].apply(lambda x: float(x))         # <---- ValueError

df['col'] = pd.to_numeric(df['col'], errors='coerce')   # <---- OK
#                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ <--- converts non-numbers to NaN


0    NaN
1    1.5
2    2.4
Name: col, dtype: float64
```

`pd.to_numeric()` works only on individual columns, so if you need to change the dtype of multiple columns in one go (similar to how `.astype(float)` may be used), then passing it to `apply()` should do the job.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['id', '1.5', '2.4'], 'col2': ['10.2', '21.3', '20.6']})
df[['col1', 'col2']] = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')


   col1  col2
0   NaN  10.2
1   1.5  21.3
2   2.4  20.6
```

Sometimes there are thousands separator commas, which throws a similar error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '2,000.4'
```

in which case, first removing them before the `pd.to_numeric()` call solves the issue.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': ['id', '1.5', '2,000.4']})
df['col'] = df['col'].replace(regex=',', value='')
#                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  <--- remove commas
df['col'] = pd.to_numeric(df['col'], errors='coerce')


0       NaN
1       1.5
2    2000.4
Name: col, dtype: float64
```

---

### In scikit-learn

This error is also raised when you fit data containing strings to models that expects numeric data. One example is various scalers e.g. `StandardScaler()`. In that case, the solution is to process the data by one-hot or label encoding the text input into a numeric input. Below is an example where a string input is one-hot encoded first and fed into a scaler model.

```py
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, OneHotEncoder
data = [['a'], ['b'], ['c']]
sc = StandardScaler().fit(data)  # <--- ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'a'


data = OneHotEncoder().fit_transform(data).toarray()
sc = StandardScaler().fit(data)  # <--- OK
```

Answer (score 0):

A good option to handle these types of erroneous values in the data is to remove it at the read_csv step by specifying na_values. This will identify strings to recognize as NA/NaN.

By default the following values are interpreted as NaN: ‘’, ‘#N/A’, ‘#N/A N/A’, ‘#NA’, ‘-1.#IND’, ‘-1.#QNAN’, ‘-NaN’, ‘-nan’, ‘1.#IND’, ‘1.#QNAN’, ‘’, ‘N/A’, ‘NA’, ‘NULL’, ‘NaN’, ‘None’, ‘n/a’, ‘nan’, ‘null’. So in your case, since it's complaining about the string 'id' in the data. you could do the following:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', na_values = ['id'])
```

This will specify values the columns with 'id' in them as null and resolve the value error when running analysis on the column of interest

Answer (score 0):

for a panda data frame or series when you gate this error do this:

```
import pandas as pd

df["columns1"] = pd.to_number(df["column1"] , errors='coerce')
```