# Convert import string to float with numpy's loadtext

Tags: python, python-3.x, ipython

I'm attempting to import text from a flat file and to convert it to float values within a single line. I've seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8420143/valueerror-could-not-convert-string-to-float-id) which has the same error, but I haven't found which characters are invalid in my input file. Or do I have a syntax error?

Import as a string an print the result:

```
data = np.loadtxt(file, delimiter='\t', dtype=str)
print(data[0:2])
... 
[["b'Time'" "b'Percent'"]
 ["b'99'" "b'0.067'"]]
```

Attempt to import as float:

```
# Import data as floats and skip the first row: data_float
data_float = np.loadtxt(data, delimiter='\t', dtype=float, skiprows=1)
```

It throws the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    data_float = np.loadtxt(data, delimiter='\t', dtype=float, skiprows=1)
  File "<stdin>", line 848, in loadtxt
    items = [conv(val) for (conv, val) in zip(converters, vals)]
  File "<stdin>", line 848, in <listcomp>
    items = [conv(val) for (conv, val) in zip(converters, vals)]
ValueError: could not convert string to float: b'["b\'99\'" "b\'0.067\'"]'
```

By the way, I've also seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269765/what-does-the-b-character-do-in-front-of-a-string-literal) which explains the `b` character, but I don't think that's the issue.

An additional troubleshooting step as suggested by the first answer:

```
data = np.loadtxt(file, delimiter="\tb'", dtype=str)
```

Returns:

```
array(["b'Time\\tPercent'", "b'99\\t0.067'", "b'99\\t0.133'",
       "b'99\\t0.067'", "b'99\\t0'", "b'99\\t0'", "b'0\\t0.5'",
       "b'0\\t0.467'", "b'0\\t0.857'", "b'0\\t0.5'", "b'0\\t0.357'",
       "b'0\\t0.533'", "b'5\\t0.467'", "b'5\\t0.467'", "b'5\\t0.125'",
       "b'5\\t0.4'", "b'5\\t0.214'", "b'5\\t0.4'", "b'10\\t0.067'",
       "b'10\\t0.067'", "b'10\\t0.333'", "b'10\\t0.333'", "b'10\\t0.133'",
       "b'10\\t0.133'", "b'15\\t0.267'", "b'15\\t0.286'", "b'15\\t0.333'",
       "b'15\\t0.214'", "b'15\\t0'", "b'15\\t0'", "b'20\\t0.267'",
       "b'20\\t0.2'", "b'20\\t0.267'", "b'20\\t0.437'", "b'20\\t0.077'",
       "b'20\\t0.067'", "b'25\\t0.133'", "b'25\\t0.267'", "b'25\\t0.412'",
       "b'25\\t0'", "b'25\\t0.067'", "b'25\\t0.133'", "b'30\\t0'",
       "b'30\\t0.071'", "b'30\\t0'", "b'30\\t0.067'", "b'30\\t0.067'",
       "b'30\\t0.133'"], 
      dtype='<U16')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to everyone who took a look at my question. I restarted IPython and was now able to execute the same code without any problems. Here's the code that worked which is identical to above.

```
data_float = np.loadtxt(file, delimiter='\t', dtype=float, skiprows=1)
```

Result:

```
In [1]: data_float
Out[1]: 
array([[  9.90000000e+01,   6.70000000e-02],
       [  9.90000000e+01,   1.33000000e-01],
       [  9.90000000e+01,   6.70000000e-02],
       [  9.90000000e+01,   0.00000000e+00],
       [  9.90000000e+01,   0.00000000e+00],
       [  0.00000000e+00,   5.00000000e-01],
       [  0.00000000e+00,   4.67000000e-01],
       [  0.00000000e+00,   8.57000000e-01],
       [  0.00000000e+00,   5.00000000e-01],
       [  0.00000000e+00,   3.57000000e-01],
       [  0.00000000e+00,   5.33000000e-01],
       [  5.00000000e+00,   4.67000000e-01],
       [  5.00000000e+00,   4.67000000e-01],
       [  5.00000000e+00,   1.25000000e-01],
       [  5.00000000e+00,   4.00000000e-01],
       [  5.00000000e+00,   2.14000000e-01],
       [  5.00000000e+00,   4.00000000e-01],
       [  1.00000000e+01,   6.70000000e-02],
       [  1.00000000e+01,   6.70000000e-02],
       [  1.00000000e+01,   3.33000000e-01],
       [  1.00000000e+01,   3.33000000e-01],
       [  1.00000000e+01,   1.33000000e-01],
       [  1.00000000e+01,   1.33000000e-01],
       [  1.50000000e+01,   2.67000000e-01],
       [  1.50000000e+01,   2.86000000e-01],
       [  1.50000000e+01,   3.33000000e-01],
       [  1.50000000e+01,   2.14000000e-01],
       [  1.50000000e+01,   0.00000000e+00],
       [  1.50000000e+01,   0.00000000e+00],
       [  2.00000000e+01,   2.67000000e-01],
       [  2.00000000e+01,   2.00000000e-01],
       [  2.00000000e+01,   2.67000000e-01],
       [  2.00000000e+01,   4.37000000e-01],
       [  2.00000000e+01,   7.70000000e-02],
       [  2.00000000e+01,   6.70000000e-02],
       [  2.50000000e+01,   1.33000000e-01],
       [  2.50000000e+01,   2.67000000e-01],
       [  2.50000000e+01,   4.12000000e-01],
       [  2.50000000e+01,   0.00000000e+00],
       [  2.50000000e+01,   6.70000000e-02],
       [  2.50000000e+01,   1.33000000e-01],
       [  3.00000000e+01,   0.00000000e+00],
       [  3.00000000e+01,   7.10000000e-02],
       [  3.00000000e+01,   0.00000000e+00],
       [  3.00000000e+01,   6.70000000e-02],
       [  3.00000000e+01,   6.70000000e-02],
       [  3.00000000e+01,   1.33000000e-01]])
```

Comment: That was my comment below. I'll be happy to delete it. But could you explain why first?

Comment: I resolved it now, see my posted answer. I could also delete the entire question since the answer was trivial, but maybe it will help someone.

Comment: Delete the question: its off topic  .   from SO------the close pop-up    .This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

Comment: It was the `skiprows=1` that solved the problem, not the restart.  `genfromtxt` could have been used to treat the 1st line as a header.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see what you mean about skiprows=1. I also had it before. Thanks for the tip about `genfromtxt`.

Comment: I investigated closing the question but I get a warning there saying I cannot close a question with answers. And now there's a positive vote and a few useful comments, so perhaps I should consider edit it instead. I'll wait a bit longer at least.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your numbers are quoted. That is, the field is `'99'`, rather than `99`. There are two ways you can do this. You can provide converter functions that strip the quotes and return a float. Or you can use the `csv` module to load your data in and then pass that data to `numpy`.

Using converter functions

```
import numpy as np
from io import StringIO

data = """'x'\t'y'
'1'\t'2.5'"""

arr = np.loadtxt(StringIO(data), dtype=float, delimiter="\t", skiprows=1, 
    converters=dict.fromkeys([0, 1], (lambda s: float(s.strip(b"'"))))
)
```

Using `csv`

```
import csv
import numpy as np
from io import StringIO

data = """'x'\t'y'
'1'\t'2.5'"""

reader = csv.reader(StringIO(data), quotechar="'", delimiter="\t")
next(reader) # skip headers
arr = np.array(list(reader), dtype=float)
```

In both examples I've uses `StringIO` so you can easily see the contents of the "file". You can of course pass the filename or file object to these functions.

Comment: I get nans while reading, i am doing `abcd = json.dumps("6.3, 2.7, 4.9, 1.8"); np.genfromtxt(StringIO(abcd), delimiter=',', dtype=float, converters=dict.fromkeys([0, 1], (lambda s: float(s.strip(b'"'))))).reshape(1,4)` returns `array([[6.3, 2.7, 4.9, nan]])`

Answer (score 1):

Could you try:

```
data = np.loadtxt(file, delimiter="\tb'", dtype=str)
```

To signify that the actual delimiter seems to include the characters "b'"?

Comment: This worked without an error, but doesn't look right. I'll add to the question now.

Comment: >>>float(b'42')

is not an issue, but what you're dealing with,

    >>>float("b'42'")

is not the same thing and errors out with

    ValueError: could not convert string to float: "b'18'"

Comment: Just updated question with the output of your suggestion.

Comment: Oops, I forgot about the quotes. Go back to your previous delimiter, sorry

Comment: Try using delimiter = '\t', and replace all of the followings strings with empty strings:

newstring = value.replace('"','').replace("b'","").replace("\\'",'')

I think that should tidy things up to the point that the values containing numbers can be converted to floats.

Comment: I resolved it now, see my posted answer. I could also delete the entire question since the answer was trivial, but maybe it will help someone.