# My beginner python project (calculator) is having trouble with inputs

Tags: python

Whenever I test my calculator to see how it deals with inputs that are not numbers, it flags up a ValueError. More precisely, this one "ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'a'". I have tried to amend this so there is a solution to dealing with non-integers but to no avail... Help is much appreciated.

Here is my code so far:

```
print("1. ADDITION ")
print("2. MULTIPLICATION ")
print("3. TAKEAWAY ")
print("4. DIVISION ")

Operator = int(input("please enter one of the numbers above to decide the operator you want. "))

while Operator > 4:
    print("Please select a number from the options above. ")
    Operator = int(input("please enter one of the numbers above to decide the operator you want. "))
    if Operator != (1 or 2 or 3 or 4):
        print("please enter one of the options above. ")
        Operator = int(input("please enter one of the numbers above to decide the operator you want. "))
    continue

while True:
    Num1 = float(input("Please enter first number. "))
    if Num1 == float(Num1):
        print("thanks! ")
    elif Num1 != float(Num1):
        Num1 = float(input("Please enter first number. "))
    break

while True:
    Num2 = float(input("Please enter second number. "))
    if Num2 == float(Num2):
        print("thanks ")
    elif Num1 != float(Num1):
        Num1 = float(input("Please enter first number. "))
    break
```

Comment: You need to look into [`try/except`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) blocks.

Comment: ...and the solution here will show you how:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8420143/valueerror-could-not-convert-string-to-float-id

Answer (score 1):

Exception handling is what are you looking for.
Smthng like this:

```
input = 'a'
try:
    int(a)
except ValueError:
    print 'Input is not integer'
```

Answer (score 0):

Please read the docs for handling exceptions:

https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions

for a float:

```
try:
    x = float(input("Please enter a number: "))
    break
except ValueError:
    print "Oops!  That was no valid number.  Try again..."
```

Comment: Thanks brunoelottero!

Answer (score 0):

Note: You should name your variables in lower case according to PEP8, see: [What is the naming convention in Python for variable and function names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159720/what-is-the-naming-convention-in-python-for-variable-and-function-names).

If you want to retry an input until you don't get `ValueError`, put it in a loop:

```
print("Please select a number from the options above.")
while True:
    try:
        operator = int(input("please enter one of the numbers above to decide the operator you want: "))
    except ValueError:
        print("Sorry, not a number. Please retry.")
    else:
        if 1 <= operator <= 4:
            break
        else:
            print("Sorry, choose a value between 1 and 4.")
```

Note: use `input` with Python 3.x or `raw_input` with Python 2.7

```
1. ADDITION
2. MULTIPLICATION
3. TAKEAWAY
4. DIVISION
Please select a number from the options above.
please enter one of the numbers above to decide the operator you want: spam
Sorry, not a number. Please retry.
please enter one of the numbers above to decide the operator you want: 12
Sorry, choose a value between 1 and 4.
please enter one of the numbers above to decide the operator you want: 2
```

Comment: Your welcome. Have you solve your problem? Python is great, isn't it?