# Yahoo API ValueError: could not convert string to float:

Tags: python, yahoo-api, yahoo-finance

i have looked various examples but i am having errors . i am using python 3.5.2 
I am trying to download yahoo minute data using Yahoo chartapi -- API with the flowing URL below.

I am getting

ValueError: could not convert string to float:

```
def read_data(passing_for_url,fp):
    all_features = []
    timestamp_list =[]
    close_list = []
    high_list = []
    low_list = []
    open_price_list =[]
    volume_list = []
    count=0
    if passing_for_url==1:

    datasetname= (urlopen('http://chartapi.finance.yahoo.com/instrument/1.0/GOOG/chartdata;type=quote;range=1d/csv').read().decode('utf-8')).split('\n')
    else:
       datasetname = fp
    for line in datasetname:
       l=line.split(',')
       #print (l)
       if(passing_for_url==1):
          if count > 16:
            fp.write(line)
          else:
            count+=1
            continue
    x = list(l[len(l)-1])
    x = x[0:len(x)-1]
    x = ''.join(x)
    l[len(l)-1]=x
    print (l)
    all_features.append(l)
    timestamp, close, high, low, open_price , volume = l
    timestamp_list.append(int(timestamp))
    close_list.append(float(close))
    high_list.append(float(high))
    low_list.append(float(low))
    open_price_list.append(float(open_price))
    volume_list.append(float(volume))  # <== Getting error here
return timestamp_list, close_list, high_list, low_list, open_price_list, volume_list
```

Below is the response sample from the URL

```
 uri:/instrument/1.0/GOOG/chartdata;type=quote;range=1d/csv
 ticker:goog
 Company-Name:Alphabet Inc.
 Exchange-Name:NMS
 unit:MIN
 timezone:EST
 currency:USD
 gmtoffset:-18000
 previous_close:835.6700
 Timestamp:1485441000,1485464400
 labels:1485442800,1485446400,1485450000,1485453600,1485457200,1485460800,1485464400
 values:Timestamp,close,high,low,open,volume
 close:827.1602,833.9300
 high:827.4200,834.6201
 low:827.0100,833.9300
 open:827.3400,833.9300
 volume:0,99800
 1485441610,833.9300,833.9300,833.9300,833.9300,99800 <== Need to start here
 1485442196,831.0830,831.0830,831.0830,831.0830,47700
 1485442503,832.3000,832.3000,832.3000,832.3000,60800
 1485442811,832.2100,832.2100,832.2100,832.2100,33000
 1485443111,831.4300,831.4300,831.4300,831.4300,41900
 1485443408,831.0120,831.0120,831.0120,831.0120,34600
 1485443712,831.8400,831.8400,831.8400,831.8400,39600
 1485443997,832.3400,832.3400,832.3400,832.3400,38400
 1485444312,831.7600,831.7600,831.7600,831.7600,36000
 1485444579,831.0001,831.4000,831.0000,831.4000,94700
```

I need only to have data from the timestamp, close, high, low, open_price , volume and below , the first 17 rows are omitted.

But i am getting an error using python 3.5.2

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float:


Traceback (most recent call last):
File "google.py", line 207, in <module>
timestamp_list, close_list, high_list, low_list, open_price_list,  volume_list = read_data(choice, fp1)
File "google.py", line 49, in read_data
volume_list.append(float(volume))
ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

Comment: [Relevant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8420143/valueerror-could-not-convert-string-to-float-id#8420179)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This piece does not understand what it is for but it deletes the last character of the volume column:

```
x = list(l[len(l)-1])
x = x[0:len(x)-1]
x = ''.join(x)
l[len(l)-1]=x
```

There is a line with the following content:

```
1485450601,828.5500,828.5500,828.4400,828.4999,0
```

But as I mentioned earlier, this removes the last character from the volume column; in other words, convert the '0' to '', which when converting to float generates the error.

In addition the last end of line must be eliminated, for this we use `strip()`

Complete code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen

def read_data(passing_for_url,fp):
    all_features = []
    timestamp_list =[]
    close_list = []
    high_list = []
    low_list = []
    open_price_list =[]
    volume_list = []
    count=0
    if passing_for_url==1:
        datasetname= (urlopen('http://chartapi.finance.yahoo.com/instrument/1.0/GOOG/chartdata;type=quote;range=1d/csv')
            .read().decode('utf-8').strip()).split('\n')
    else:
        datasetname = fp
    for line in datasetname:
        l=line.split(',')
        #print (l)
        if(passing_for_url==1):
            if count > 16:
                fp.write(line)
            else:
                count+=1
                continue
        all_features.append(l)
        timestamp, close, high, low, open_price , volume = l
        timestamp_list.append(int(timestamp))
        close_list.append(float(close))
        high_list.append(float(high))
        low_list.append(float(low))
        open_price_list.append(float(open_price))
        volume_list.append(float(volume))
    return timestamp_list, close_list, high_list, low_list, open_price_list, volume_list
```

Comment: fantastic it works great. thank you. If i wanted to download or do all the stocks in S&P 500 list and do a loop for each of them . to accomplish the same thing, how would i go about it

Comment: I do not understand your question, explain.

Comment: Currently the above code will only read or download a single stock realtime minute data . I was wondering how to download all the minute data for stocks listed on S&P 500 list  ( or may be just 100 of them to start , usually they are about 500 company names on the list that make up of S&P 500 )

Comment: Is the content of the page corresponding to the url updated every time interval?