# "ValueError: could not convert string to float" error in scikit-learn

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I'm running the following script:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
dataset = pd.read_csv('data/50_Startups.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:, :-1].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, 4].values
onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features=3, 
handle_unknown='ignore')
onehotencoder.fit(X)
```

The data head looks like:
[data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mEkVF.png)

And I've got this:

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'New York'

I read the answers to [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8420143/valueerror-could-not-convert-string-to-float-id) questions and then opened scikit-learn  [documentations](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html#encoding-categorical-features), but how you can see scikit-learn authors doesn't have issues with spaces in strings

I know that I can use `LabelEncocder` from `sklearn.preprocessing` and then use OHE and it works well, but in that case

```
In case you used a LabelEncoder before this OneHotEncoder to convert the categories to integers, then you can now use the OneHotEncoder directly.
warnings.warn(msg, FutureWarning)
```

massage occurs.

You can use [full csv file](https://pastebin.com/RtwkfsHJ) or

```
[[165349.2, 136897.8, 471784.1, 'New York', 192261.83],
[162597.7, 151377.59, 443898.53, 'California', 191792.06],
[153441.51, 101145.55, 407934.54, 'Florida', 191050.39],
[144372.41, 118671.85, 383199.62, 'New York', 182901.99],
[142107.34, 91391.77, 366168.42, 'Florida', 166187.94]]
```

5 first lines to test this code.

Comment: My input, as you can see from code, is csv file

Comment: try: dataset.info() to check the types of data that you have in your dataframe.

Comment: I've add 5 first lines and link to pastebin with full content of the file

Comment: The 'State' column full of 50 non-null objects. Now I see the problem, but anyway have no idea how to fix it without using `LabelEncoder`

Comment: What would you expect 'New York' to be as a floating point number? *Why* would you think it has anything to do with a space in the string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is `categorical_features=3` that hurts you. You cannot use `categorical_features` with string data. Remove this option, and luck will be with you. Also, you probably need `fit_transform`, not `fit` as such.

```
onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore')
transformed = onehotencoder.fit_transform(X[:, [3]]).toarray()
X1 = np.concatenate([X[:, :2], transformed, X[:, 4:]], axis=1)
#array([[165349.2, 136897.8, 0.0, '0.0, 1.0, 192261.83],
#       [162597.7, 151377.59, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 191792.06],
#       [153441.51, 101145.55, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 191050.39],
#       [144372.41, 118671.85, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 182901.99],
#       [142107.34, 91391.77, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 166187.94']])
```

Comment: In that case the whole dataset tranforms to categorical data, not only 3d column

Comment: You can choose which columns to transform.

Comment: I ran this code: `onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore')
onehotencoder.fit(X[:, 3])` and got this error: `ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:`

Comment: Because you pass a 1D array instead of a 2D array. You ought to pass `X[:, [3]]` or `X[:,3].reshape(1,-1)`.

Comment: OK, I did it like you said. Now if I apply this `X = onehotencoder.transform(X[:, [3]]).toarray()` I losing my first 3 colums. If I apply this `X = onehotencoder.transform(X[:, 3]).toarray()` the same error occurs

Comment: You have to combine the transformed columns with the original columns. I am afraid that your understanding of how Python (and Numpy) works is still insufficient for carrying out complex tasks, and strongly suggest that you read a good numpy tutorial.

Comment: Sorry, I've been facing this problem whitin 3 hours and it 4.35 a.m. so I'm bit tired. Could you please past the whole working code that transforms my 4 colums to 6 colums correctly?

Comment: Following your advice I cheked how np.concatinate works and get the same result, but your code looks cleaner, thanks for carring me

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer, make_column_transformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

columntransformer = make_column_transformer(
(OneHotEncoder(categories='auto'), [3]),
    remainder='passthrough')


X = columntransformer.fit_transform(X)
X = X.astype(float)
```