# ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'none' while reading csv data

Tags: python, pandas, missing-data

I am reading csv data for building model.

I do understand missing values processing so I haved filled them using radiun and zero. And dropped few parameters which are of no interest.

I manually checked csv file applying filter for `empty` value. Which ever fields give empty, I tried to fill them. But still I am getting above error.

Here is my code -

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

dataset = pd.read_csv("model__newdata.csv",header = 0)

#Data Pre-processing
data = dataset.drop('shift_location_id',1)
data = data.drop('status',1)
data = data.drop('city',1)
data = data.drop('open_positions',1)

#Find median for features having NaN
median_role_id, median_specialty_id = data['role_id'].median(),data['specialty_id'].median() 
median_shift_id = data['shift_id'].median()
median_shift_id = data['specialty_id'].median()

data['shift_id'].fillna(median_shift_id, inplace=True)
data['role_id'].fillna(median_role_id, inplace=True)
data['specialty_id'].fillna(median_specialty_id, inplace=True)
data['years_of_experience'].fillna(0, inplace=True)
data['specialty_id'].fillna(0, inplace=True)

#Start training

labels = dataset.shift_location_id
train1 = data
algo = LinearRegression()
x_train , x_test , y_train , y_test = train_test_split(train1 , labels , test_size = 0.20,random_state =1)

# x_train.to_csv("x_train.csv", sep=',', encoding='utf-8')
# x_test.to_csv("x_test.csv", sep=',', encoding='utf-8')

algo.fit(x_train,y_train)
algo.score(x_test,y_test)
```

Error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-99f96096832a> in <module>
     32 # x_test.to_csv("x_test.csv", sep=',', encoding='utf-8')
     33 
---> 34 algo.fit(x_train,y_train)

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'none'
```

Any suggestion how to resolve this?

Edit 1 - 
Sample data - https://gist.githubusercontent.com/karimkhanvi/d69c98352aaaaed87f787a20c05307f8/raw/a45bb471fc1ee5095a1d0c3809a8362c001f639e/temp.csv

Edit 2 - 
I already checked [ValueError: could not convert string to float: id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8420143/valueerror-could-not-convert-string-to-float-id) before I posted.

I appreciate if you check that I have not issue with the data type of any parameter.

ValueError: could not convert string to float: **'none'**

I am facing issue due to `empty` values. And I have tried to deal with this issue which does not solve my problem. That is why I have posted this question.

Edit 3
I tried to check if any value `isnull`

```
data.isnull().values.any()
data.isnull().sum()
```

Which gives `false` and

```
shift_id                 0
user_id                  0
shift_organization_id    0
shift_department_id      0
role_id                  0
specialty_id             0
years_of_experience      0
nurse_zip                0
shifts_zip               0
dtype: int64
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8420143/valueerror-could-not-convert-string-to-float-id

Comment: Show your CSV data

Comment: @Alderven: Please check link in edit

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ValueError: could not convert string to float: id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8420143/valueerror-could-not-convert-string-to-float-id)

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev: please check edit 2

Comment: WFM with your data and code if I use `dataset = pd.read_csv("model__newdata.csv",header = 0, dialect = 'excel-tab')` (since the csv you gave is tab-separated). Python 2.7.15 win64, latest `pandas`, `numpy`, `scipy` and `sklearn` (installed with `--force-reinstall`).

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev: When i add `excel-tab`, it says `KeyError: "['shift_location_id'] not found in axis"` while reading first value. Also this is purely csv file. not excel converted