# ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Y'

Tags: python, pandas

As i try to convert an object type column to float, I am getting `ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Y'`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df_train = pd.read_csv('loan_prediction/train_u6lujuX_CVtuZ9i.csv')
df_train_y = df_train.iloc[:, 12].values

df_train_y.astype(float)
```

Comment: Can you show us an example of the data in that column?

Comment: Are you sure that **all** elements of the **thirteenth** column of "train_u6lujuX_CVtuZ9i.csv" are numbers?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8420143/valueerror-could-not-convert-string-to-float-id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help you to find the non-numeric values in your data set.

First, create a data frame, and set certain elements of Column 12 to non-numeric values:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

nrows, ncols = (10, 15)
data = np.arange(nrows * ncols).reshape((nrows, ncols))
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df.iloc[2:5, 12] = 'x'
```

Second, extract column 12, and convert to numeric type:

```
df_2 = df.iloc[:, 12].copy()
df_2 = pd.to_numeric(df_2, errors='coerce')
```

Third, find the non-numeric values (with a Boolean mask):

```
mask = df_2.isna()
print(df[mask].iloc[:, 12])

2    x
3    x
4    x
Name: 12, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks jsmart. Using the above code, I found that my datatype is an object throughout my 12th column. However how can i convert those object data into integers or float?

Comment: If you execute `pd.to_numeric('12', errors='coerce')`, then you'll get 12 (as an integer).  But if you execute `pd.to_numeric('abc', errors='coerce')`, then you'll get 'nan' (not a number) -- because 'abc' is not a string representation of a number.  The `errors='coerce'` returns a number (if the conversion was successful) or nan otherwise.

Comment: Program returned nan for all index of Column 12. But i want all string values to be changed to numeric.

Comment: Hi, can you post the first 10 or 20 lines of your data file?