# ValueError: could not convert string to float in reading csv file, how to fix it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

This type of question has been asked several times. Still, I can not find a similar issue to my case. If there is anything similar, please let me know.

The python file is

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
import csv
import numpy as np

x = []
y = []

with open('example2.txt','r') as csvfile:
    plots = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ')
    for row in plots:
        #print(row[0],type(row[0]))
        x.append(float(row[0]))
        y.append(float(row[1]))
```

example2.txt is

```
0.0  0.5
0.1  0.6
```

I got an error message as

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "plot.py", line 14, in <module>
    y.append(float(row[1]))
ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

Some link, e.g., [ValueError: could not convert string to float: id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8420143/valueerror-could-not-convert-string-to-float-id), suggests that the reason is, there is extra space in the value. I cannot find extra space by printing the row[0] values :(

Comment: Your file is delimited by two spaces. `row` is `['0.0', '', '0.5']`. `row[1]` is an empty string, which cannot be parsed as a float.

Comment: Thank you so much! It works! Cheers!