# could not convert string to float: 'Runny_nose'

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier

Disease_data = pd.read_csv("Disease_dataset.csv")

X = Disease_data.drop(columns='Diseases')
y = Disease_data['Diseases']

model = DecisionTreeClassifier() 
model.fit(X, y)
```

I get this error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Runny_nose'
```

I tried

```
Disease_data = Disease_data['Diseases'].astype(float)
```

and

```
music_data = pd.to_numeric(music_data, errors='coerce')
```

instead I get empty columns

Answer (score 0):

Some of your lines might don't have valid float data.

Visit [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8420143/valueerror-could-not-convert-string-to-float-id) thread for more info.